# Is it possible to have multiple client certificates for connecting in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have an app which has multiple keys required by multiple application servers, az.crt, ks.crt. The public keys are used to access 2 Kafka topics from 2 different servers.
One of the keys is for connecting to a Mongodb server which requires 1 certificate with TLS/SSL and a different cipher . There is the Azure connection which also requires a public certificate with user name and password for connecting with a different cipher suite. The only way I can see for connecting using certificates is like this:

```js
// config1 // first kafka instance server1
ssl: {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./ks.crt', 'utf-8')
},
sasl: {
  mechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
    username: env.kafkaUsername1,
    password: env.kafkaPassword1,
}
// config2 - 2nd Kafka instance server2
ssl: {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ca: [readFileSync('./az.crt', 'utf-8')],
},
sasl: {
  mechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-256',
    username: env.kafkaUsername2,
    password: env.kafkaPassword2,
}
```

This will make it impossible to handle the 2 certificates which have different connection criteria. Though both keys are issued by the same CA, the username and passwords are different for both. It seems there is only 1 mechanism to load the certificates in the ssl object and since I have 2 situations, one for az.crt and ks.crt, I need 2 declarations requiring the ssl{} section.

Is it possible to solve this issue using any NodeJS options?

Comment: Username and password of what? Certificates are unrelated to usernames and passwords. Your code probably uses some library to do HTTPS calls through some object so just duplicate those objects so that each one can have its own parameter to connect to a specific endpoint.

Comment: I missed adding the extra information on the need for the passwords. I have included that information. It is required for the sasl configuration of the 2 Kafka connection information.

Comment: So just use 2 separate connections "handler", each with its own set of configuration. Not seeing really where the problem is, but not seeing as well the code that uses that configuration data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a second KafkaJS instance.

```
const kafka_mongo = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'x',
  brokers: ['x:9092'],
  ssl: {
    cert: readFileSync('./ks.crt', 'utf-8')
  },
  sasl: {
    mechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
    username: env.kafkaUsername1,
    password: env.kafkaPassword1,
  },
})

const kafka_azure = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'y',
  brokers: ['y:9092'],
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ca: [readFileSync('./az.crt', 'utf-8')],
  },
  sasl: {
    mechanism: 'SCRAM-SHA-256',
    username: env.kafkaUsername2,
    password: env.kafkaPassword2,
  },
})
```